# Magento Admin Login Error: Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "1178" already exist

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I get this error when trying to log in to my admin. Please help!

```
/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(576): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))

Trace: 
0 /lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(576):Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order)) 
1 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533):Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load() 
2 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php(61): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
```

Comment: Can you add all the code from _prepareCollection() in /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php(61)

Comment: How do I use group? In what file and file path?

Comment: How d?o I add the code from the code from _prepareCollection() in?

Comment: The inforamtion provided by R.S. is correct. PLEASE READ: If you ever encounter this problem. Go to Myphpadmin database and select sales_flat_order. Then find the order assigned to the entity id, in my case it was 1178. I just changed the customer's order id to 0008 because I knew this number had never been used. It worked, no duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is stating that your Varien_Data_Collection filter return two order with the same ID 1178.

This may be the result of two things,

1. You/module is doing a custom query that return multiple record with the same id. You may need to use a group by since Varien_Data_Collection can not have duplicate id
2. Duplicate recode in sales_flat_order (next to impossible because entity_id should be a primary key

How many rows the code below return

```
select * from sales_flat_order where entity_id = 1178
```

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question! Here is the full error message I'm getting when trying to log in to my admin:

Comment: Did you install any module recently that affect sales functionality? Also try manually clear you cache.

Comment: Thank you so much for paying attention to my question! Total of 35 rows. I wasn't able to attach all of them in here. See below:     Trace:
#0 /lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(576): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php(61): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()

Comment: Line 576 of Db.php says this:       $this->addItem($item);

Comment: Can someone help me? Anyone?